# Issues with click function on iPhone 5 and lower

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I've got some jquery code to show/hide a div on click/touch.
This is the code:

```
var checkMobile = function(){

var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);


  if ( isTouch ) {

    var clickHandler = "click";

if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement){
clickHandler = "touchstart";
}


$j('.product_more_info').on(clickHandler,function(){

$j(this).closest('.products_overlay').find('.product_less_info').show('fast');
     $j(this).hide('fast');
$j(this).closest('.products_overlay').addClass('overlay_test');

});

$j('.product_less_info').on( clickHandler,function(){

$j(this).closest('.products_overlay').find('.product_more_info').show('fast');
     $j(this).hide('fast');
$j(this).closest('.products_overlay').removeClass('overlay_test');
}); 

}


});
  checkMobile();
```

This works fine on all android devices, iPads and iPhone 6 etc. However, on iPhone 5S it seems to break. On touch it does show the `product_less_info`
and adds the `overlay_test` class but as soon as the user let's go it disappears again. This doesn't happen on any of the other tested devices.
I've also tried using

```
 $j('.product_more_info').on(‘touchstart’,function(){}
```

but I've still got the same problem.
Has anybody else come across this issue or any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I don't get your logic about setting `var clickHandler = "click";` inside `if ( isTouch )` block and then rechecking for `if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)` still inside it?! From where did you get this snippet? Anyway your code has synthax error so post the relevant code you are using. And as a side note, have you try to set `.product_more_info, .product_less_info {cursor: pointer; }` and maybe setting `tabindex="-1"` on these elements, depending which kind of type these elements are.